# Why Image.Save() in C# does not always give the same serialized result and how to serialize an image in a deterministic way?

Tags: c#

I serialize images using the following code:

```
public static string SerializeImage(Image image)
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(memoryStream, image.RawFormat);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

and deserialize the images by doing the following

```
public static Image DeserializeImage(string serializedImage)
{
    byte[] imageAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(serializedImage);

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.Length))
    {
        memoryStream.Write(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.Length);

        return Image.FromStream(memoryStream, true);
    }
}
```

If I have an image and does

```
string serializedImage1 = SerializeImage(image);
Image deserializedImage = DeserializeImage(serializedImage1);
string serializedImage2 = SerializeImage(deserializedImage );
```

Then

```
serializedImage1 == serializedImage2;
```

as expected. *But* it is not always the case.

If I serialize an image on Process 1, and then redeserialize and reserialize it on Process 2, then the result of the reserialization on Process 2 is not the same as on the Process 1. Everything works, but a few bytes in the beginning of the serialization are different.

Worst, if I do the same thing on 2 different dll (or thread, I'm not sure), it seems the serialization result is not the same too. Again, the serialization/deserialization works, but a few bytes are different.

The image the first time is loaded with the following function :

```
public static Image GetImageFromFilePath(string filePath)
{
    var uri = new Uri(filePath);
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(uri);
    bitmapImage.Freeze();

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var pngBitmapEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        pngBitmapEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
        pngBitmapEncoder.Save(memoryStream);
        Image image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);

        return image;
    }
}
```

Note however that it happens even if the image is loaded twice with the DeserializeImage() function.

The tests I have done are with ImageFormat.Jpeg and ImageFormat.Png.

First question, why it does this ? I would have expected the result to be always the same, but I suppose some salt is used when doing the Image.Save().

Second question : I want to have a deterministic way to serialize an image, keeping the image format intact. The goal is to save the image in a DB and also to compare serialized images to know if it already exists in the system where this function is used.

Comment: What kind of image is it, jpg?

Comment: @James I have updated the question, I tested with ImageFormat.Jpeg and ImageFormat.Png

Comment: It might not be possible.  See https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/83745/is-a-jpg-guaranteed-to-produce-the-same-pixels

Comment: see if it is the same on the 3rd time.

Comment: Is this .NET Core or Framework? Which version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I discovered while trying to solve this that a png or jpeg Image object inside C# has some metadata associated to it and doing what I was doing is just not a reliable way to compare images.

The solution I used was derived from this link

https://insertcode.wordpress.com/2014/05/13/compare-content-of-two-files-images-in-c/

So what I do finally is save the images inside the system with the `SerializeImage(Image image)` function previously described, and when I want to consume it I deserialize it with the `DeserializeImage(string serializedImage)` function previously described. But when I want to compare images I use the following functions

```
public static bool ImagesAreEqual(Image image1, Image image2)
{
    string image1Base64Bitmap = GetImageAsBase64Bitmap(image1);
    string image2Base64Bitmap = GetImageAsBase64Bitmap(image2);

    return image1Base64Bitmap.Equals(image2Base64Bitmap);
}

public static string GetImageAsBase64Bitmap(Image image)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(image))
        {
            bitmap.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

That convert the image to raw bitmap before comparing them.

This does a perfect job for me in all my needed cases : the formats of the images are saved/restored  correctly, and I can compare them between them to check if they are the same without having to bother with the possibly different serialization.